# Remove tableprefix with .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We make a .net Core application. For that we have to use an existing Database. This database is used from other programs too, so we cannot change something on it. So it's database first. The problem is, that we have some prefix in our tables. The tables always starts with tbl and the fields start with an individual prefix:

Tablename: `tblPerson`

Fields: `PeName`, `PeStreet`, ...

So if I use PowerTools the classes always have this prefixes. Because our database is quiet big, we use the powertools everytime, when we need a new table form the db. Because of that, we can't change them directly in the `DbContext`.

Can I remove the prefix somehow? Or change them globaly in my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rename tables and columns during the reverse engineering process by adding a file called efpt.renaming.json in the project folder. Below is the format of this file:

```
[
  {
    "UseSchemaName": true,
    "SchemaName": "machine",
    "Tables": [
      {
        "Name": "alert_ui",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Name": "alarm_name",
            "NewName": "NameOfTheAlarm"
          },
          {
            "Name": "columnOldName1",
            "NewName": "columnNewName1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "UseSchemaName": true,
    "SchemaName": "master",
    "Tables": [
      {
        "Name": "measure",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Name": "alarm_name",
            "NewName": "NameOfTheAlarm"
          },
          {
            "Name": "columnOldName1",
            "NewName": "columnNewName1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "UseSchemaName": false,
    "SchemaName": "dbo",
    "Tables": [
      {
        "Name": "work_cells",
        "NewName":  "WorkCell",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Name": "columnOldName1",
            "NewName": "columnNewName1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the link to this file on github : https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/blob/master/src/GUI/EFCorePowerTools/efpt.renaming.json

Comment: This works! But another question to this: Our database is very big. So the renaming file would be extremly big and maybe not readable. Is it possible to make something like a partial file of that? The renaming in multiple files?

Answer (score 5):

You can have different model class names and property names to the database table name and column name.

Use the `Table` and `Column` attributes to tell EF core the names in the database.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("tblPerson")]
public class Person
{
    [Column("PeName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("PeStreet")]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

You can also you can use the Fluent API to define these properties in `OnModelCreating` in your `DbContext`.

[Data annotations documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt)

Comment: I can't do this, because we do not add the full database once to the solution because the db is very big. So when we need a new table we import it with the powertools. And when we execute the powertools again, it will generate every table again and overrides the existing dataanotations.

Answer (score 4):

you can remove table / column prefixes using regex pattern in `efpt.renaming.json` file:

```
[
  {
    "UseSchemaName": false,
    "SchemaName": "dbo",
    "TableRegexPattern": "^(tbl|vw)",
    "TablePatternReplaceWith": "",
    "ColumnRegexPattern": "^(tbl|vw)",
    "ColumnPatternReplaceWith": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: Very important: this wont work without "Tables":[] property eg.:
[
   {
      "ColumnPatternReplaceWith": "Id",
      "ColumnRegexPattern": "Guid$",
      "SchemaName": "dbo",
      "Tables": [ ],
      "UseSchemaName": false
   }
]

Answer (score 0):

you can use Fluent API to configure an entity to map it with database table.

```
  public class SchoolContext: DbContext 
    {
        public SchoolDBContext(): base() 
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Configure default schema
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Admin");

            //Map entity to table
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("StudentInfo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Standard>().ToTable("StandardInfo","dbo");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just add to @extragen answer. That approach works but only in case you have unechecked `Use table and column names directly from the database` in EFPT UI here:

[image: EFPT UI]

or in the file `efpt.config.json` set value:

```
"UseDatabaseNames": false
```

because if it is `true` those renaming changes wont be applied.